# Chrome not loading webpages. No errors displayed

Tags: google-chrome

I just upgraded to the latest version of Chrome, and it will no longer load any websites.
When I try to access any website it simply displays the loading symbol and nothing else happens. It does not give me any sort of errors even after half an hour of this.

Comment: Launch chrome from a terminal see if it displays any errors in there. Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? or does `curl ipinfo.io/ip` display your external ip?

Comment: @j-money I can ping 8.8.8.8 and I get my ip fine from curl. Terminal does give me two errors: "GCM channel request failed" and "Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -336".

Comment: And the old version of chrome worked fine?

Comment: @j-money It was working fine until earlier today when it crashed and no longer wanted to even launch (which is what made me update from a by now quite old version).

Comment: it seems most searches point to your wifi card... are you able to use firefox for browsing? Or are you presneted with the same issue?

Comment: @j-money Firefox works fine.

Comment: @j-money Thank you for your patience. For now I just decided to grab an old version of Chrome to use, since that at least works.